# display a tree of category, subcategory by given category id

Tags: php, codeigniter, recursion, treeview

Though i'm using codeigniter but it does not matter if someone can help me in simple **recursive function**.
i have a table called '`tbl_member`' where there is 3 field `member_id,parent_id,name`
I want a `tree structure` for particular `member id`.

Ex if i send a `member_id(10)` it will show **all** `children(sub_member)` of that `member`

Answer (score 1):

Does it help??

```
 function get_tree($member_id){
  $result=$this->db->get_where('table',array('member_id'=>$member_id));
  $data=$result->row_array();
    $n=$this->get_child($data['member_id']);
      foreach($n as $l){
        $data[]=$l;
       }
    print_r($data);
}


function get_child($parent_id){
$result=$this->db->get_where('table',array('parent_id'=>$parent_id));
$row = $result->result_array();
foreach ($row as $key => $m) {
  if (is_array($m) && count($m) != NULL) {
      $me=$this->get_child($m['member_id']);
      foreach($me as $res){
            $row[$key][]=$res;
       }
    }
 }
  return $row;
}
```

Comment: @user1987095 this hits database many times.. I 've tested it.

Comment: when there is a multiple child of a single root it is not working because $data=$result->row_array();  return single row

Comment: you can use result_array() and foreach() loop for it . Anyway i ve edited it now you can check.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getMemberTree($id) {
$q =  $this->db->get_where('tbl_member', array('parent_id' => $id));
if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach($q->result() as $row) {
        $first_level[] = $row;
    }
    foreach($first_level as $r) {
        $member_id = $r->member_id;
        $m = $this->db->get_where('tbl_member', array('parent_id' => $member_id));
        if($m->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach($m->result() as $mrow) {
                $second_level[] = $mrow;
            }
        }
    }
    $data[] = $first_level;
    $data[] = $second_level;

    return $data;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

These solutions require many, many database hits. Consider a hierarchy table structure instead:

http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2012/10/nested-data-with-mahana-hierarchy-library

Comment: jmadsen,"Nabin Kunwar" answer must hit database many times because it is a n level tree.

Comment: you can build an n-level tree with the other technique I show, hitting the db once

Comment: It's all explained; it's just Codeigniter code - you display like any other data.